# Change placeholder opacity

Tags: html, css, forms, input

I am changing the opacity of an input field like this...

```
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First name"><br>
    </form>
</body>

body{background:black}
input{height:30px;opacity:.5;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hbakrvnv/

This works but it also changes the opacity of the placeholder.  How can I keep the placeholder text as white on top of the 50% opacity input field?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css Check the answer on this question. It explains setting the placeholder color

Comment: Its not the colour I am trying to change, its the opacity

Comment: Thats included in the link.

Comment: Answer updated, sorry I had a mistake but now it's working. also added code snippet and JSFiddle.

Answer (score 14):

You can use this method in WebKit browsers:

```css
body{background:black}
input{height:30px;opacity:.5;}
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
     color: black; /*Change the placeholder color*/
     opacity: 0.5; /*Change the opacity between 0 and 1*/
}
```

```html
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First name"><br>
    </form>
</body>
```

If you are using IE10 (or higher) it is not possible to change the opacity, as you can see described in Internet Explorer Dev Center: [Click Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hbakrvnv/4/

**EDIT: Fixed CSS mistake**

Answer (score 5):

Since ~2017 you can use the `::placeholder` CSS pseudo-element like so

```
::placeholder {
  color: green;
}

.force-opaque::placeholder {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

- Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::placeholder
- CanIUse: https://caniuse.com/css-placeholder